# Python librosa.display cannot be imported

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, librosa, spectrum

My python version is `3.7.4`,and Librosa version is `0.8.0`

Below is my code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, sr = librosa.load('./test/s1071511.wav', sr=None)

plt.figure()

librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr)
plt.title('Beat wavform')
plt.show()
```

I want to show the spectrum of a wav file, but I got:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa.display'; 'librosa' is not a package`

I have searched the related documents for a while.
Could you help me? I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to load the audio file using librosa package?
If yes,  then try using installing librosa version 0.8.0

Comment: At first I used librosa 0.8.0,it worked.But when I want to change the version to 0.7.2,I type pip install 0.7.2,it just become my question

Comment: have you installed version 0.7.2 properly? Because I tried and it is working for me